# A submit button doesn´t work when click on it on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, submit

I have a problem with Javascript and a submit button that worked until now. I didn´t change anything but when i revise all my project i´ve seen it doesn´t work... I have a table with some qualifications of each pupil. With Javascript i add a row to write a new qualification and clicking on "Agregar" it takes to another screen called "procesar_nota.php" that add to database. However, when i click on "Agregar" it doesn´t work and nothing happens. What´s the problem?

Here´s my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();

$asignatura=$_GET['asignatura'];

$id_usuario=$_GET['id_usuario'];

$id_alumno=$_GET['id_alumno'];

$curso=$_GET['curso'];

$clase=$_GET['clase'];

?>

<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Página principal de gestión del colegio"  />
    <title> Gesti&oacute;n de alumnos y profesores de colegios </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/anadir_filas_notas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function eliminar(id_nota,curso,clase)
      {
            if (confirm("¿Estás seguro de que quieres eliminar la nota?"))
                 location.href='eliminar_nota.php?id_nota=' + id_nota + '&curso=' +curso + '&clase=' +clase;
      }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="agrupar">
    <header id="cabecera">
        <?php 
        $titulo = "Notas de clase";
        include("header.php");
        ?>
    </header>
    <nav id="menu">

    </nav>
    <section id="seccion">
        <article>


      <?php

require_once("conexion_base_datos.php"); 

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$hora=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

$consulta = "select id_nota, round(calificacion,1) as calificacion, DATE_FORMAT(`fecha`,'%d/%m/%y  %H:%i:%s') AS fecha, asignatura, id_alumno, id_usuario, id_trimestre, tipo_nota from notas where asignatura='".$asignatura."' and id_alumno='".$id_alumno."' and id_usuario='".$id_usuario."' and tipo_nota='clase' order by id_trimestre, fecha";

$resultado = mysql_query($consulta);
echo "
<h2>Notas de clase</h2>
<table border=1 id='tabla' width=auto>
<tr>
<th>Calificación</th>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Trimestre</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>


<input type='hidden' name='asignatura' id='asignatura' value='".$asignatura."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='id_usuario' id='id_usuario' value='".$id_usuario."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='id_alumno' id='id_alumno' value='".$id_alumno."'>
        ";
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    echo "<tr><form action='actualizar_notas.php?curso=".$curso."&clase=".$clase."' method='post'>
        <td><input type='text' name='calificacion' value='".$fila['calificacion']."'></td>
        <td>".$fila['fecha']."</td>
        <td>".$fila['id_trimestre']."</td>
        <td><input type='submit' value='Modificar'></td>
        <td><a href='javascript:eliminar(".$fila['id_nota'].",".$curso.",\"".$clase."\")'>Eliminar</a></td>
        <input type='hidden' name='id_nota' id='id_nota' value='".$fila['id_nota']."'>
        </form>
    </tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

echo "<input type='button' id='agregar' value='Agregar fila' />";

echo "
<h2>Media de las notas de clase por trimestres</h2>
<table border=1 id='tabla' width=auto>
<tr>
<th>Trimestre</th>
<th>Nota media</th>
</tr>";

$consulta2 = "select round(avg(calificacion),1) as media, id_trimestre, tipo_nota from notas where asignatura='".$asignatura."' and id_alumno='".$id_alumno."' and id_usuario='".$id_usuario."' and tipo_nota='clase' group by id_trimestre";



$resultado2 = mysql_query($consulta2);

while ($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2))
{
    echo "<tr>
        <td>".$fila2['id_trimestre']."</td>
        <td align='right'>".$fila2['media']."</td>
    </tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($conexion);
$_SESSION['asignatura']=$asignatura;
$_SESSION['id_usuario']=$id_usuario;
$_SESSION['id_alumno']=$id_alumno;

echo " <div id='boton_atras'>
<a href='mostrar_alumnos_clase.php?curso=".$curso."&clase=".$clase."'><img src='Imagenes/boton_volver.png' height='33' width='40' alt='Botón'></a>
</div>";
?>
      </article>  
    </section>
    <aside id="columna">
        <div id="lapiztop">
        </div>
        <div id="lapizmed"> 
            <ol>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div id="lapizbottom">
        </div>
    </aside>
    <footer id="pie">
        <?php include("footer.html");?>
    </footer>       
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

And my Javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var asign=$('#asignatura').val();
    var id_user=$('#id_usuario').val();
    var id_pupil=$('#id_alumno').val();


    $("#agregar").on('click', function(){
        $('#tabla > tbody:last').after("<tr><form action='procesar_nota.php' method='post'><td><input type='text' name='calificacion' value=''></td><td></td><td></td><td><input type='submit' value='Agregar'></td><input type='hidden' name='asignatura' id='asignatura' value="+asign+"><input type='hidden' name='id_usuario' id='id_usuario' value="+id_user+"><input type='hidden' name='id_alumno' id='id_alumno' value="+id_pupil+"></form></tr>");


    });   

});
```

A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the button dynamically then you should bind the click handler in this manner:

```
$(document).on('click','#agregar',function(){
        //your code here
 });
```

Comment: do you have multiple buttons of same id?

Comment: No, is the only one i have.

Comment: On the other hand, i´ve seen that the problem is with the new version of Google Chrome, the 34, on 32 it works well. What have changed on the update of Google Chrome for not working now?

Comment: It's nothing wrong with the browser. Like I said earlier, you adding the button dynamically and the button you are referring doesn't have a class of Id. So better give it a class and then bind the event handlers for it in the same way described above. Another point is that you aren't closing the input tags properly, if your document is not html5 then you should close them properly.